# Need to Migrate Documents from SharePoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013 with meta deta

Tags: 2013, 2010, document-library, people-picker, document-migration

Documents from document library in SharePoint 2010 and need to be moved to SharePoint 2013 site with all meta deta.

Also there is people picker column in the library which needs to be moved.

Powershell, Console App(CSOM or server side), etc anything is welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to spend money, I've used Metalogix Content Matrix to do this type of task (including within a farm, between farms of both the same and different versions, and from a farm to the cloud). It worked very well for me and can save metadata and versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below methods to move files while maintaining all metadata properties and version history:

Method 1: Using Content and Structure to move files with versions and Metadata

Method 2: Programmatically – move document with version history

Using PowerShell to maintain file version history when moving/copying files between SharePoint sites

http://expert-advice.org/2017/01/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-itemsdocuments-metadata-version-history/